# Entity copy was already assigned to a different entity (Spring/Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, relational-database

EDIT: Have tried for hours, but still haven't found a solution.

Right now I have 3 tables in my database - Booking, Restaurant and RestaurantTable. I have a one to many mapping between Restaurant and RestaurantTable (a restaurant can have many tables, but a table can have only one restaurant). I have a file called "newTable.jsp" that inserts new tables to the restaurant. But when I try to insert a table, it gives me an error, saying that an entity copy was already assigned to a different entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="restaurant_name")
    private String restaurantName;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<RestaurantTable> table;

    // Getters and setters
```

My "RestaurantTable.java":

```
@Entity
@Table(name="restaurant_table")
public class RestaurantTable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="table_size")
    private int tableSize;

    @Column(name="table_number")
    private int tableNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id")
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    // Getters and setters
```

My "newTable.jsp"

```
<body>
<jsp:include page="../fragments/menu.jsp"/>
<div id="body">
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

        <h2>Add New Table</h2>

        <form:form method="POST" commandName="table" modelAttribute="table">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Table size:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="tableSize" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Table number:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="tableNumber" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>

    </section>
</div>
<jsp:include page="../fragments/footer.jsp"/>

</body>
```

My RestaurantTableController:

```
@Controller
public class RestaurantTableController {


    @Autowired
    private RestaurantService restaurantService;

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantTableService restaurantTableService;

    @RequestMapping(value="restaurant/table/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addRestaurantTable(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("table", new RestaurantTable());
        return "newTable";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "restaurant/table/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addRestaurantTable(@PathVariable Long id, @ModelAttribute ("table") RestaurantTable table) {
        // Get a Restaurant object and add the table to it.
        Restaurant restaurant = restaurantService.getRestaurant(id);
        table.setRestaurant(restaurant);
        Set<RestaurantTable> tableSet = restaurant.getTable();
        tableSet.add(table);
        restaurant.setTable(tableSet);
        restaurantService.updateRestaurant(restaurant);
        return "editRestaurant";
    }

}
```

The {id} in RestaurantTableController is a Restaurant id, it is passed along from "editRestaurant.jsp".

My updateRestaurant method:

```
@Override
public void updateRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.merge(restaurant);
    logger.info("Restaurant record updated successfully, Restaurant Details=" + restaurant);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Added "table.setRestaurant(restaurant);" to RestaurantTableController.
It now lets me add one table, but when I try to add another one it gives me this error:

```
    30-Mar-2016 16:59:59.363 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error occurred while storing entity [Table number 0]. An entity copy [ee.helmes.bootcamp.model.RestaurantTable#6] was already assigned to a different entity [Table number 0].] with root cause
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error occurred while storing entity [Table number 0]. An entity copy [ee.helmes.bootcamp.model.RestaurantTable#6] was already assigned to a different entity [Table number 0].
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.EventCache.put(EventCache.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:886)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:868)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:876)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:863)
    at ee.helmes.bootcamp.dao.RestaurantDaoImpl.updateRestaurant(RestaurantDaoImpl.java:31)
    at ee.helmes.bootcamp.service.RestaurantServiceImpl.updateRestaurant(RestaurantServiceImpl.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.updateRestaurant(Unknown Source)
    at ee.helmes.bootcamp.controller.RestaurantTableController.addRestaurantTable(RestaurantTableController.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My database looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `restaurant`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `restaurant` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `restaurant_name` TEXT,
  `address` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `restaurant_table`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `restaurant_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `table_size` int,
  `table_number` int,
  `restaurant_id` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant_id`) references `restaurant`(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize the owner side of the association, which is the only one Hibernate cares about to know if an association exists:

```
table.setRestaurant(restaurant);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! It now lets me add one table, but when I try to add another table it gives me this error: 

An entity copy [ee.helmes.bootcamp.model.RestaurantTable#6] was already assigned to a different entity [Table number 0].

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Are you sure you don't have additional cascade options? FWIW, I almost never use merge. Instead, I work with managed entities, in a single transaction: load the restaurant, create and add a table to the restaurant, let Hibernate manage the persistence. This is both easier, more efficient, and more correct.